# Thin film sheet-resistance (van der Pauw method)

Tags: electrical-engineering, systems-design

A well-known method to measure sheet resistance is the van der Pauw method. Looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pauw_method) they state that the cloverleaf configuration is the most advised. Two questions naturally arise:

1. Why is this the best configuration?
2. Why is it a cloverleaf and not a fully "filled" circle?

Answer (score 1):

As van der Pauw noted in his [original paper](http://pleclair.ua.edu/PH255/templates/van_der_Pauw/1958%20Van%20der%20Pauw%20(Philips%20Tech%20Rev)%20A%20method%20of%20measuring%20the%20resistivity%20and%20Hall%20coefficient%20on%20lamellae%20of%20arbitrary%20shape.pdf), the incisions in the cloverleaf shape "substantially reduce the error due to the finite dimensions of the contacts" compared to simple circle.  A cloverleaf is effectively a small central circular sample with four large contact pads, and you can be a little less precise in where connect to those pads.

According to [Koon](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224475508_Effect_of_contact_size_and_placement_and_of_resistive_inhomogeneities_on_van_der_Pauw_measurements), to achieve resistivity measurements with 1% errors, a typical cloverleaf is about 4 times more forgiving than a simple circle for small displacements of the contact points on the edge of the sample. Even a  simple square sample with contacts at the four corners is about 3 times more forgiving than a simple circle.

For 1% Hall coefficient measurements, the square is actually the best, being about 12 times more forgiving than the circle, while the cloverleaf is only about 7 times more forgiving.